# New methods added to c# dll are not recognized?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

In an existing VS2012 project I was given, I added a new method to a c# dll, compiled it, and put the dll in the proper iis bin directory. I am calling the dll methods from ASP.NET jayrock rpc .js files. The existing methods in the dll still seemed to work proper, but the new methods did not seemed to get called and/or recognized at all.

As a test I added some new code to existing methods, and that seemed function properly, so I know it's reading from the dll I compiled.
Also I renamed an existing method, and tried to call it, but that strangely did not work, even though the only thing I changed was the name of the previously functioning method that I was able to call.
I ran a "clean" on the VS project and did rebuilds, but that didn't help.
I put all the code on two different iis machines, but got the same results.
I triple checked all the code, but don't see any thing out of place.

Has anyone experienced an issue like this, or know what might cause it?

Comment: Are you sure you put the right dll? It seems like you still have the old one.

Comment: Pretty sure it's the right dll, because I added some code changes to an existing method, and the code changes ran properly.

Comment: Have you re-reference the dll?

Comment: It just references by the class name stored in a string. I changed the class name as a test, but that had no effect.